# as3 Object araba is not moving

Tags: actionscript-3

Here is my code at below and im keep getting this error i've became a freak for 3 days please help me guys.I will be appriciate your comments.

```
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
    import flash.ui.Keyboard;
    import flash.display.Bitmap;
```

`stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, basili);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, degil);
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, giris);


var yukari:Boolean = false;
var asagi:Boolean = false;
var sola:Boolean = false;
var saga:Boolean = false;
var hiz:Number = 5;
var araba:MovieClip=new araba();    
var masa:MovieClip =new masa();


function giris(event:Event):void
{
if ( sola && !saga ) {
araba.x -= hiz;
araba.rotation = 270;
}
if( saga && !sola ) {
araba.x +=hiz;
araba.rotation = 90;
}
if( yukari && !asagi ) {
araba.y -= hiz;
araba.rotation = 0;
}
if( asagi && !yukari ) {
araba.y += hiz;
araba.rotation = 180;
}
if( sola && yukari && !saga && !asagi ) {
araba.rotation = 315;
}
if( saga && yukari && !sola && !asagi ) {
araba.rotation = 45;
}
if( sola && asagi && !saga && !yukari ) {
araba.rotation = 225;
}
if( saga && asagi && !sola && !yukari) {
araba.rotation = 135;
}
if( araba.y < masa.y ){
araba.y = masa.height;
}
if( araba.y > masa.height ){
araba.y = masa.y;
}
if( araba.x < masa.x ){
araba.x = masa.width;
}
if( araba.x > masa.width ){
araba.x = masa.x;
}
} 
function basili (event:KeyboardEvent):void
{
switch( event.keyCode )
{
case Keyboard.UP:
yukari = true;
break;
case Keyboard.DOWN:
asagi = true;
break;
case Keyboard.LEFT:
sola = true;
break;
case Keyboard.RIGHT:
saga = true;
break;
}
}
function degil(event:KeyboardEvent):void
{
switch( event.keyCode )
{
case Keyboard.UP:
yukari = false;
break;
case Keyboard.DOWN:
asagi = false;
break;
case Keyboard.LEFT:
sola = false;
break;
case Keyboard.RIGHT:
saga = false;
break;
}
}
<code>`

Comment: What is `araba`? Is that a MovieClip in your library?

Comment: it is object that have to move when KEY_DOWN happening.

Answer (score 0):

From

```
var araba:MovieClip=new araba();    
var masa:MovieClip =new masa();
```

To

```
var araba:MovieClip=new MovieClip();    
var masa:MovieClip =new MovieClip();
```

If araba and masa are actually your custom classes, then you forgot to import those 2 classes.

Use Flash Builder or Flash Develop for your development for auto imports and smart error checking.

Comment: well it solved my problem and thank you about your answer but as you might know salvation makes occur new problems :) since araba object is my car and it doesn't moves do you have any idea which makes it moves when i press correct buttons ? :)

Comment: You will find everything you need to know on Kirupa site. For this particular problem: http://www.benoitfreslon.com/actionscript-move-an-object-with-keyboard-with-absolute-controls

Comment: i've checked the link but that code type is a bit different than mine for instance i've used multiple key detection and that code doesn't supporting that type of code so still thx for the link but it doesn't useful.